# vbScript - InputBox into .accdb , blank?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, insert

After 9 hours of research and trial and error, I've come to all of you with this current issue I am having with another script I wrote to input data into a database. I'll simplify the focal point of this problem in the code view. I have 3 fields, one is a timestampe at the end of the SQL such as .... & now() & "')". That inserts FIND, but by variable inputboxes insert blank data.

```
Option Explicit
Dim ib
Dim sql1, constring, con
constring="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\users\user\documents\database1.accdb;"
sql1="INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES('" & ib & "')"
set con = createobject("adobd.connection")
con.open constring

Do
    ib=inputbox("Input Data")

    IF ib="quit" OR ib="QUIT" THEN
    con.close

   ELSE con.execute sql1
  End If
Loop WHILE ib<>"quit" AND ib<>"QUIT"
```

It is appending rows into the database, but they are blank. Ive designed the table to take short text of <255 chars.

I also ran a test query from within the database and it inserts what I tell it to, but the inputbox data, for some reason, is not making it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
sql1="INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES('" & ib & "')"
```

concats an (empty) `ib` into `sql1` **before** the loop. `con.execute sql1` will insert that into the database until you quit.

Try

con.execute "INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES('" & ib & "')"

and optimize when it works.

Comment: I recall doing that, however with the actual statement i had resulted in an overload error.. maybe i did something wrong, ill have to revisit it again tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

```
Do
    ib=inputbox("Input Data")
    If LCase(ib) <> "quit" THEN
        con.execute "INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES('" & ib & "')"
    End If
Loop WHILE ib<>"quit" AND ib<>"QUIT"
con.close
```

You need to recreate the string that you will execute for each value that you retrieve

Comment: wont that create 2 rows then? one with a value in column1 and null in column 2.. and the other with null in column1 and value in column 2? Pardon my ignorance, because Ive dealt mainly with excel data application, but now realize the value of using access and sql over the past month

Comment: i understand - thanks! so i can actually remove the defined sql1